# FacesContext redirect with Application context

Tags: jsf, redirect

I want to implement a redirect to a page in my application.
My current problem is that I not got the application name.

The following code redirect to **localhost:8080/index.hmtl**:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .redirect("/index.html");
```

But I want to have:
**localhost:8080/myapp/index.html**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requestcontextpath is what you need! it is in externalcontext

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath()+"/index.xhtml");
```